# How to display kernel's PSI (Pressure Stall Information)?

Tags: 16.04, kernel, ram

I am running Ubuntu 16.04 and my Linux kernel version is 4.4.0. How can I enable the kernel's [PSI](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/accounting/psi.html)? Or is there a tool that is similar?

Comment: Htop can display it

Answer (score 1):

Pressure information for each resource is exported through the respective file in `/proc/pressure/` – `cpu`, `memory`, and `io`.

The PSI command for your CPU is:

```
some avg10=0.00 avg60=0.00 avg300=0.00 total=0
```

and for memory and IO:

```
some avg10=0.00 avg60=0.00 avg300=0.00 total=0

full avg10=0.00 avg60=0.00 avg300=0.00 total=0
```

The “some” line indicates the share of time in which at least some tasks are stalled on a given resource.

The “full” line indicates the share of time in which all non-idle tasks are stalled on a given resource simultaneously. In this state actual CPU cycles are going to waste, and a workload that spends extended time in this state is considered to be thrashing. This has severe impact on performance, and it’s useful to distinguish this situation from a state where some tasks are stalled but the CPU is still doing productive work. As such, time spent in this subset of the stall state is tracked separately and exported in the “full” averages.

More detail can be found in my [source](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/accounting/psi.html), which I added as the link in the first graf of your query.

Comment: Is it available on kernels of any version?

Comment: I do not know is it is available in any version.

Answer (score 1):

For "monitoring" you probably want a running display of current values. You can achieve this by employing `watch`, like

```
watch cat /proc/pressure/*
```

(although here it is difficult to discern what line shows which category)
or

```
watch "(echo CPU; cat /proc/pressure/cpu ; echo IO; cat /proc/pressure/io; echo MEMORY; cat /proc/pressure/memory)"
```

which displays something like

> ```
> CPU
> some avg10=0.00 avg60=0.00 avg300=0.04 total=51646098
> IO
> some avg10=0.00 avg60=0.00 avg300=0.09 total=20413087
> full avg10=0.00 avg60=0.00 avg300=0.08 total=16237739
> MEMORY
> some avg10=0.00 avg60=0.00 avg300=0.00 total=0
> full avg10=0.00 avg60=0.00 avg300=0.00 total=0
> ```